# Randomly split array using split() and sample() in R

Tags: arrays, r, split

i have created an array consisting of N values, say

```
a <- array(dim = c(x, y)).
```

I want to partition the array into K groups, where array values are randomly assigned to one of K groups. For example if K = 2 and N = 10, one subarray could have 7 values while the other would have 3. The values in all subarrays must sum to N      (e.g., 7 + 3 = 10).

I know using split() and sample() is probably the easiest route. I have tried

```
split(a, sample(a, 2))
```

but this does not work as it should.

Any ideas?

Comment: What data do you want after splitting? array? vector?

Comment: @ChiPak I would like it to be K subarrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a <- array(c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
k <- 3
split(sample(a),1:k)

# [1] 2 3
# 
# $`2`
# [1] 4 5
# 
# $`3`
# [1] 6 1
```

Comment: How can I change the implementation to have differing numbers of values per subarray, instead of equally splitting values between subarrays?

Comment: Something like `split(sample(a), sample(1:k, length(a), replace = TRUE))` would randomly assign each item to a group in range 1:k